# Display position of a y-maximum using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, vline

I used `ggplot` to create a plot:

```
pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x=xval, y=as.numeric(BS))) + 
    geom_point(shape=21) + 
    xlab("Threshold") + 
    ylab("BS") + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=df$xval[as.numeric(df$BS) == max(as.numeric(df$BS))],color='red') +
    geom_hline(yintercept=max(as.numeric(df$BS)),color='darkblue',linetype=2)
```

The red line tells me where the maximum of `BS` is.

Is there a way to display the x-position and y-position of this value?

It should be something like (for example): `P(0.5, 0.8)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_label()` here after filtering your data. Here using the `mtcars` dataset as an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = qsec)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = mtcars$disp[as.numeric(mtcars$qsec) == max(as.numeric(mtcars$qsec))],color='red') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = max(as.numeric(mtcars$qsec)), color = 'darkblue', linetype = 2) +
  geom_label(data = . %>% filter(qsec == max(qsec)), 
             aes(label = paste0("P(", disp, ", ", qsec, ")")), hjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a text annotation using the `geom_text()` function in `ggplot`:

```
pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x = xval, y = as.numeric(BS))) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21) + 
  xlab("Threshold") + 
  ylab("BS") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = df$xval[as.numeric(df$BS) == max(as.numeric(df$BS))], color = 'red') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = max(as.numeric(df$BS)), color = 'darkblue', linetype = 2) +
  geom_text(
    x = df$xval[as.numeric(df$BS) == max(as.numeric(df$BS))],
    y = max(as.numeric(df$BS)),
    label = paste0("P(", round(df$xval[as.numeric(df$BS) == max(as.numeric(df$BS))], 2), ", ", round(max(as.numeric(df$BS)), 2), ")"),
    vjust = -1.5,
    color = "black"
  )
```

The `paste0()` function is used to concatenate the position information in the desired format (e.g., "P(0.5, 0.8)").

Adjust the `vjust` parameter as needed to fine-tune the vertical positioning of the text.